# Optimize MySQL query using range and group by on large table

Tags: mysql

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs_view_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_D05BC6799FDS15210` (`job_id`),
  KEY `FK_YTGBC67994591257` (`account_id`),
  KEY `jobs_view_stats_created_at_id_index` (`created_at`,`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_YTGBC67994591257` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `job_views_jobs_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79976587 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci COMMENT='New jobs views system'
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as view, job_id
from jobs_view_stats
WHERE jobs_view_stats.created_at between '2022-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-11-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY jobs_view_stats.job_id
```

Execution plan:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | jobs_view_stats | null | range | IDX_D05BC6799FDS15210,jobs_view_stats_created_at_id_index | jobs_view_stats_created_at_id_index | 5 | null | 1584610 | 100 | Using index condition; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort |

This query takes 4m to complete I want to reduce it to take minimum time.

Comment: you can create [partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-types.html) by `YEAR_MONTH`.

Comment: Try a compound index on `(created_at, job_id)` or `(job_id, created_at)`. An index on `(created_at, id)` is probably unnecessary, there aren't many instances where you want to search by both a time range *and* an ID; index only `created_at`.

Comment: @Schwern Still searching from `1603308` rows. taking more than 4 min.

Comment: Have you tried running the query on the table without the jobs_view_stats_created_at_id_index index? It could just scan the whole table (how many rows are on it?), but this index is making it do it a funny way. It might be faster without that index though you need to know if anything else on your system requires it. You could maybe try dropping the index, running your query, then adding it again. I don't know how long it would take to rebuild the index on a table of this size (probably minutes?). At least then you would know why it is so slow.

Comment: @SimonGoater After removing the index rows are  25774075 and the total rows are 28384645. It takes 5m 54s

Comment: I see, so that didn't help. It might have been faster if there were fewer rows not selected by the query. You could try giving mysql more memory to play with in the config file or put your tables on fast(er) SSDs. Other than that, you could change your application to maintain the count somewhere so you can just select it rather than having to scan such a lot of data.

Comment: @SimonGoater The issue is due to this `job_views_jobs_id_fk` index. When I tried after removing this index `job_views_jobs_id_fk` and creating an index on `created_at, job_id`. Query working fine

Answer (score 1):

In your execution plan, you are returning 1584610 rows that are then grouped by, which in turn uses a temp table to sort through and group (slow).

jobs_view_stats_created_at_id_index contains also 'id' which will make the key cardinality excessively large, could try instead adding job_id to the key as that is what you are grouping by.

I think the main issue is your where clause returns over 1.5 million rows that have to all load into a temp table to then be re-read in full to be grouped by.

You need to bite off smaller chunks i think.

I'm going to assume you are using a programming lang to envoke the DB calls (like PHP), if so you could try

```
SELECT DISTINCT job_id
from jobs_view_stats
WHERE jobs_view_stats.created_at between '2022-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-11-30 23:59:59'
```

then when you have the job_id list

do smaller queries looping over the results from the first

```
SELECT count(*) FROM jobs_view_stats where job_id = *theid*
```

or if there are many different job_id's batch them

```
SELECT count(*) FROM jobs_view_stats where job_id IN('id1', id2, id3....)
```

for a pure MySQL resolution, I would create a temp memory table of all the job_ids as a memory table using

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temptable`
(
 job_id INT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=MEMORY   

INSERT INTO 'temptable' SELECT DISTINCT job_id
 from jobs_view_stats
 WHERE jobs_view_stats.created_at between '2022-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-11-30 23:59:59'
```

Then

```
SELECT count(*) as view, job_id FROM jobs_view_stats where job_id = (SELECT job_id FROM `temptable`)
```

this is all totally untested so might be typos.

Answer (score 0):

Change `COUNT(id)` to `COUNT(*)` since it does not need to check `id` for being `NOT NULL`

Add

```
INDEX(job_id, created_at)
INDEX(created_at, job_id)
```

Either of those will be "covering".  (I don't know which is better; the Optimizer will know.)

Drop the index `(job_id)`, as being redundant.
Unless you specifically need `(created_id, id)`, drop it.

For even more performance, build and maintain a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .  Then perform the query against it.  Such a summary table might have `PRIMARY KEY(job_id, created_date)` and daily counts for each day for each job.